# how to sort a list by the strings that have the most alphabetical characters python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

If there is a list with some strings, how the list be sorted where the strings within it are sorted by the most alphabetical of their character sequences if their character sequences were to be rearranged in alphabet order? For instance: ["tank", "ream", "ram", "banter"] would result in ["banter", "ream", "ram", "tank"]. Is this possible to achieve without loops and comprehension? i.e using lambdas?

As someone mentioned below sorted(words, key=sorted)) does work here but now I'm wondering about case sensitivity. How could this be handled if case sensitivity took precedence, meaning alphabet order of the character sequence but putting uppercase first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, shouldn't the output be:

```
['banter', 'ream', 'tank', 'ram']
```

Because for this input

```
words = ["tank", "ream", "ram", "banter"]
```

If we alphabetically rearrange each word

```
>>> [''.join(sorted(word)) for word in words]
['aknt', 'aemr', 'amr', 'abenrt']
```

And sorting that would result in the first output when reordered to the original wording.

If so, then this should work:

```
>>> sorted(words, key=sorted))
['banter', 'ream', 'tank', 'ram']
```

Comment: how would you account for case sensitivity with this though? Let's say if uppercase takes precedence?

Answer (score 0):

just use `list.sort()`

```
#define list
a = ["tank", "ream", "ram", "banter"]

#sort list
a.sort()
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, unfortunately this returns an incorrect result because using just list.sort() returns ['banter', 'ram', 'ream', 'tank']